# Install unetbootin on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shared-library, unetbootin

I'm trying to install UNetbootin on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I downloaded the executable file from this [link](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and followed the instructions below:

> If using Linux, make the file executable (using either the command
>   chmod +x ./unetbootin-linux, or going to Properties->Permissions and
>   checking "Execute"), then start the application, you will be prompted
>   for your password to grant the application administrative rights, then
>   the main dialog will appear, where you select a distribution and
>   install target (USB Drive or Hard Disk), then reboot when prompted.\

So I typed on my terminal `sudo chmod +x unetbootin-linux-584` and tried to execute the binary file with `./unetbootin-linux-584` but got this output:

> ./unetbootin-linux-584: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libXrandr.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

However when I checked for libraries `libXrandr` on my system I actually found them

```
$> locate libXrandr
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr_ltsq.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr_ltsq.so.2.2.0
```

so I really don't have a clue of what's the problem and how can I fix it, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install unetbootin` in a terminal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is you are trying to run a 32 bit application on a 64 bit host.

unetbootin is in the repos

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unetbootin

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: that worked, I didn't know it was in the reps...anyways that error is weird, any idea on that?

Comment: My guess is as above, what is the output of `file ./unetbootin-linux-584` ?

Comment: you were right!  this is the output: `./unetbootin-linux-584: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped.`  I was downloading the 32 bit version...thks so much!
`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, this problem happens when you try to run 32-bit programs in a 64-bit Linux O.S

I solved executing this command (Installing libxrandr2:i386)

```
sudo apt-get install libxrandr2:i386
```